# How do I make a 'table' with the following text aligned in the center?

Tags: tables, math-mode

I'm trying to align some text as shown in the picture:
[image]

Can someone help with how to do this?

Comment: Is this really maths? It does look like more text than math. However, take a look at the `array` environment (similar to `tabular`) and the `\overset` command. The arrows could be `\longleftarrow`, `\longrightarrow`, and `\longleftrightarrow`.

Comment: @Skillmon The arrows with the text above it do need the math environment. I've used $\xleftarrow{\text{text}}$ and $\xrightarrow{\text{text}}$ to get the arrows in the top row and $\leftrightarrow$ for the arrows in the second row. I will look into your suggestion for a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Then show us some code of what you've accomplished so far and ask for help on a specific problem. Also you can use a textual environment and put `$\xleftarrow{\text{text}}$` into this.

Comment: @Skillmon I've answered my own question, I hope that's ok. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Skillmon I've found the solution.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}

\newcommand{\spaa}{\mathrm{Spec}(A)}
\newcommand{\Ak}{\textbf{Alg}_k}
\newcommand{\Grp}{\textbf{Grp}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\begin{document}
\centering
$\begin{array}{ccccc}

\mathbf{Sch}/k & \xleftarrow{\spaa \mapsfrom A} & \Ak^{\mathrm{op}} & \xrightarrow{A \mapsto \Hom(-, A)} & {\Grp}^{\Ak} \\
\left\{
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Affine\\
    Schemes
\end{tabular}
\right\}& \leftrightarrow & \Ak^{\mathrm{op}} & \leftrightarrow & \left\{
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Representable\\
    functors
\end{tabular}
\right\}  \\
\left\{
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Affine group\\
    schemes
\end{tabular}
\right\}  & \leftrightarrow & \left\{
\begin{tabular}{@{}L@{}}
    \text{Groups in}\\
    \Ak^{\mathrm{op}}
\end{tabular}
\right\}  & \leftrightarrow&\left\{
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Affine\\
    groups
\end{tabular}
\right\}
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]

Comment: You accidentally marked your code as a citation, and not as code. Also you might use `\longleftrightarrow` instead of `\leftrightarrow`.

Comment: @Skillmon Oh, I was wondering why the code wasn't displaying correctly. Thanks. And I'll replace the arrows with longer ones.